# how to finish dart class from navigate one class to another class like android Native Applications(finish the previous class)?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

if we navigate screen two from screen one how would I finish screen one, class
in the background(currently, the first screen it still in background i.e, not finishes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WillPopScope widget and cancel the back button request so that the page will not go back

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
    return 
    WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
          Future.value(
              false); //return false
        },
    child:
    Scaffold( //scaffold code)

    );
  }
```

And you can also set the following inside the AppBar widget to hide the back button

> automaticallyImplyLeading: false

Answer (score 2):

Call `Navigator.of(context).pop(`) before navigating to the next screen.

Also you can use the more convenient method pushReplacement

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => NewPage()));
```

Answer (score 1):

> In Flutter You Can User Navigator.of(context).pop();
>
> below code, close your current page, navigate and open your new page.

```
Navigator.of(context)..pop()..pushNamed("/ui/dashbord", arguments:{});
```

Define you all route path in main class, after you can access all classes using route name.

in dart we can user ".." operator for run multiple statement in single line.